# Need nose >= 0.10.0 error while attempting to install Theano on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, numpy, nose, theano

Overall I've had a hell of a time getting Theano to work, I've gotten to the stage where I *think* everything in stalled correctly.
Running:

```
    sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-dev python-pip python-nose g++ libopenblas-dev git
```

and the console tells me that I have the latest version of everything.

Running:

```
    sudo pip install Theano
```

and I'm told that all requirements are satisfied.

Yet when I try to do the tests as the guide recommends

```
python -c "import numpy; numpy.test()"
```

gives me

```
Running unit tests for numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/josh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/nosetester.py", line 351, in test
self._show_system_info()
  File "/home/josh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/nosetester.py", line 204, in _show_system_info
nose = import_nose()
  File "/home/josh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/nosetester.py", line 74, in import_nose
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Need nose >= 0.10.0 for tests - see http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose
```

I've done a thorough search online and all the solutions I've seen seem to be based around installing nose but I've definitely got nose installed and above 0.10.0.

Comment: What output do you get when you call `python -c "import nose;print nose.__version__;print nose.__file__"`?

Comment: Consider installing into a [`virtualenv`](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html) next time - it will avoid all kinds of headaches with setting up your Python path

Comment: @ali_m When I call `python -c "import nose;print nose.__version__;print nose.__file__"` I get `ImportError: No module named nose`

Comment: Try `pip install -U --force --user nose`. This will install `nose` in `~/.local/`, where you seem to have installed numpy. Don't `sudo` this command!

Comment: It says it's already up to date. `josh@josh-GA-78LMT-S2P:~$ pip install -U --user nose
Requirement already up-to-date: nose in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...`

Comment: Sorry, I added the `--force` directive in an edit to my comment, which would force it to install nose anyway. I don't think that's the root of the problem though. What output do you get from `which python` and `which pip`?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/python` for python, and `/usr/bin/pip` for pip

Comment: See my answer in the other thread - I would just use anaconda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Anaconda` simply try this whet your `conda` environment is activated:

```
conda install nose
```

I had the same issue and `conda install` works without any `pip`!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested I installed [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/), that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue in running theano.test() under Windows 7.
I used Anaconda to create separate environment for python3.4.
I installed theano using conda install for the above python3.4 environment.
But theano.test() gave me same error message as you have.
So I downloaded the nose-parameterized zip from github
and installed it using the following :

```
((theanoBasic)) C:\pythonZipsPy34\manualZip\nose-parameterized-master>python setup.py install --record installNotes.txt
```